# How to integrate angular 4 webapp inside another webapp (jsp style)?

Tags: angular, jsp, web-applications

I have a old webapp that is deploy on tomcat 7 and i want to make a new section with angular 4. To make some test i have put a dist folder with index.html inside it `<base href=".">`  inside a webapps/project folder and add a iframe inside a html of existing webapp, iframe contain a

```html
<html>
<body>

   <app-root></app-root> 
</body>
</html>
```

But anything is show inside the iframe. If i insepect the code is show only the code :

```
 <html>
<body>

   <app-root></app-root> 
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how to implemnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with SystemJS you can use this tutorial:

[Angular 4 in jsp with SystemJS](https://www.quora.com/Can-anybody-show-me-an-example-to-include-Angular-2-Typescript-with-existing-Spring-MVC-gradle-project)

With webpack you should import all js and css that are inside a `index.html` under `dist` folder, like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../angularWeb/dist/inline.136b795d1580a6687eae.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../angularWeb/dist/polyfills.8eba0ab53b5457105d75.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../angularWeb/dist/vendor.091a5f9daa5d2223e9cf.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../angularWeb/dist/main.b235b84cde360ec37e99.bundle.js"></script>

<link href="../angularWeb/dist/styles.f6578a3761ef80039afc.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

is a copy paste of dist/index.html. And put all file of angular project under webapp folder.